# What's the etiquette for providing multiple answers to a question?

Tags: discussion

How should you answer questions to puzzles when you have multiple guesses/iterations of your thoughts for answering a puzzle?

For example: [This puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/11973/2806) I have 3 distinct guesses which happen to be iterations of each other, but could stand alone.

[This answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/12380/2806) was the 3rd answer from the user where he explored different methods to coming up with a proof.

In short (TLDR;): should each puzzle be 1 answer per user or is there some threshold for each answer being put into separate answers?

**Edit**: Just found [the meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice) on the subject, but it might be good to figure out how it applies to this site.

Answer (score 8):

In general, I agree with the [Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice) that you found.  Different answers should usually be posted separately, so that each answer may be judged on its own merits.

But for the [example](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11972/find-a-straight-tunnel/11973#11973) you provided, where the question is looking for the smallest number possible, I think what you did (putting all your answers into the same answer) is appropriate.  Your first and second guesses were beaten by your third guess, so it'd be kind of pointless to have your first and second guesses as separate answers.  But it's still interesting to see your iterations all in the same answer.

For your other [example](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/12380/2806), the question was asking for proofs, and the guy had 3 valid proofs, so I think posting them all separately was the way to go.